# Wcf Streamed transfer over http causes exception on first call

Tags: .net, wcf, http, iis, streaming

We are in the process of converting our .Net Remoting codebase to Wcf. A small portion of the methods we used before uses [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) instances between the client and the server to transfer large files and such. Both the client and the server are web applications hosted in IIS.

Initially, we had problems with these methods working over Wcf, because the [httpTransport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.httptransportbindingelement.aspx) uses a [buffered](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.transfermode.aspx) transfer mode by default, thus not supporting `Stream` objects as parameters or return values. After changing the transport configuration to use `StreamedResponse` (or `Streamed`, which is `StreamedResponse` plus `StreamedRequest`), we get an exception on every first call to the service (for instance after compiling the service provider, or restarting IIS):

```
The input source is not correctly formatted. 

[XmlException: The input source is not correctly formatted.]
   System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3) +815516
   System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowInvalidBinaryFormat(XmlDictionaryReader reader) +34
   System.Xml.XmlBinaryReader.ReadNode() +2367693
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.ReadFromBodyContentsToEnd(XmlDictionaryReader reader, EnvelopeVersion envelopeVersion) +65
   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest) +319
   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message message, Object[] parameters) +741

[CommunicationException: Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation '[MyMethod]'. The input source is not correctly formatted.]
   [webforms page 'Page_Load' stacktrace]
```

We are currently using a custom binding stack (to enable binary encoding over http), configured like this:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <customBinding>
        <binding>
          <binaryMessageEncoding/>
          <httpTransport transferMode="StreamedResponse" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    ...
  </system.serviceModel>
```

How can I find out why this happens only when the host web application needs to start? When I refresh the page right after this error, everything seems to work correctly again for all other pages. Perhaps it is somehow timeout related, since it takes time to wake up the server after a recompile/pool recycle/webconfig change/etc?

**Update:**

I tested increasing all timeouts over the default values on the client and server bindings like this:

```
<binding closeTimeout="10:00:00" 
         openTimeout="10:00:00" 
         receiveTimeout="10:00:00" 
         sendTimeout="10:00:00">
  <binaryMessageEncoding />
  <httpTransport transferMode="Streamed" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />
</binding>
```

Nothing seems to have changed though, as I still get the same exception on the first access after the server is updated.

**Update 2:**

I just found [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ff186d74-a95b-4f50-ac54-c7ba42778650/silverlight-to-wcf-xmlexception-the-input-source-is-not-correctly-formatted?forum=wcf) which seems to be the same problem I'm having. The author states:

> I forgot to mention that this happens only once per time that the
>   server is launched.

His problem seems to be a mismatch between the endpoint stacks on client and server though, which is not my case.

Answer (score 0):

After customizing our environment further, this error stopped happening.

What I did was remove the parameter from the transport component in the configuration file.

I then created a custom behavior that adds it dynamically to the endpoint based on it's contract interface: if the contract has any methods that either return or receive a Stream object, I inspect it's endpoint binding and add the `Streamed` mode to the binding's httpTransport component, like this:

```
public sealed class DynamicStreamingEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    private bool m_contractHasStream;

    void IEndpointBehavior.Validate(ServiceEndpoint _endpoint)
    {
        IEnumerable<MethodInfo> streamMethods =
            from method in _endpoint.Contract.ContractType.GetMethods()
            where method.GetCustomAttribute<OperationContractAttribute>() != null && (
                typeof (Stream).IsAssignableFrom(method.ReturnType) ||
                method.GetParameters()
                    .Select(_parameter => _parameter.ParameterType)
                    .Any(_type => typeof (Stream).IsAssignableFrom(_type)))
            select method;

        m_contractHasStream = streamMethods.Any();
    }

    void IEndpointBehavior.AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint _endpoint,
                                                BindingParameterCollection _bindingParameters) {}

    void IEndpointBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint _endpoint, EndpointDispatcher _endpointDispatcher)
    {
        if (!m_contractHasStream) return;

        BindingElementCollection bindingElements = _endpoint.Binding.CreateBindingElements();
        bindingElements.OfType<HttpTransportBindingElement>().Single().TransferMode =
            TransferMode.Streamed;
        _endpoint.Binding = new CustomBinding(bindingElements);
    }

    void IEndpointBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint _endpoint, ClientRuntime _clientRuntime)
    {
        if (!m_contractHasStream) return;

        BindingElementCollection bindingElements = _endpoint.Binding.CreateBindingElements();
        bindingElements.OfType<HttpTransportBindingElement>().Single().TransferMode =
            TransferMode.Streamed;
        _endpoint.Binding = new CustomBinding(bindingElements);
    }
}
```

Then, by creating a custom extender element, I can configure it globally in the config:

```
public sealed class DynamicStreamingBehaviorElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get { return typeof (DynamicStreamingEndpointBehavior); }
    }

    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new DynamicStreamingEndpointBehavior();
    }
}
```

And here is the final configuration:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        ...
        <add name="dynamicStreaming" 
             type="[namespace].DynamicStreamingBehaviorElement, [assembly]"/>
        ...
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
    ...
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          ...
          <dynamicStreaming />
          ...
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      ...
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I'm still not sure why the problem happens if I leave it on `Streamed` mode for all endpoints though.